# Why is my Minecraft Skin Messed up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently created a skin through the skin creator on Newgrounds.com, which I have used before. I uploaded the skin and went into the game. I went onto an online server and my character was mostly black and parts on the skin were in the wrong places, ie- The torso was on the head. I thought that I had chosen the player model wrong so I tried the other one and it was still messed up. Please help!

Here is the skin:

[image: My Skin]

And this is what it shows up as in game:

[image: Ingame]

Comment: could you post up a screen shot of what you looked like in game?

Comment: i added it to the post

Answer (score 3):

By the looks of your texture pack, it seems the game is trying to wrap an 8x8 skin around a 32x32 body. Usually Minecraft would catch that and keep it from contorting, but for an unknown reason it didn't. Try disabling the texture pack, restarting the game, or upload the default Steve skin and re-upload your own. Hope this helped.

EDIT: If all else fails, delete minecraft.jar and re-install.

Comment: I did all of that and nothing worked :'(

Answer (score 2):

After update 1.7.9, the skin system changed ([Mentioned Here I think](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Skin)), if you're on that version with an old skin it could pose a problem. Try [this](http://www.minecraftskinconverter.com/) to convert your skin if it is needed. Otherwise i'm clueless..